# SQL data transfer between two databases on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a SQL query I can use to transfer data from a table in one database to a table in another database on a same server?

For example:

```
UPDATE DB1.Table 
SET 
   DB1.Table.Column1 = DB2.Table.Column1,
   DB1.Table.Column2 = DB2.Table.Column2,
   DB1.Table.Column3 = DB2.Table.Column3;
```

Comment: See ChristopherBrown's answer assuming the two databases are located on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an insert into statement?

```
INSERT INTO DB2.Table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 
Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM 
 DB1.TABLE
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTS (Data Transformation Service) feature of SQL Server 2005.

Here is the good [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm) that explains the process step by step.